# Android Studio java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when static game assets are called to be drawn

Tags: java, android, static, libgdx

I've been working on a LIBGDX game for a while and last week I updated my Android Studio to Version 2.1.2. After the update I started getting the `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` when the render method in the screen class tries to draw a static image which was called from a different class.
"
        batcher.begin();
        batcher.draw(Assets.rockWall, 0, 0, 160, 90);
"

Here is my error log:

> 07-24 12:12:10.702 9442-9489/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   GLThread 32587
>                                                    Process: com.dotabmot.game, PID: 9442
>                                                    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.StartMenuScreen.render(StartMenuScreen.java:108)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474)
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
>                                                     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file:
>   trollWalk1.png
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:148)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:100)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:92)
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.Assets.(Assets.java:112)
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.StartMenuScreen.render(StartMenuScreen.java:108) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248) 
>                                                     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file:
>   trollWalk1.png (Internal)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:145)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:100) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:92) 
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.Assets.(Assets.java:112) 
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.StartMenuScreen.render(StartMenuScreen.java:108) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248) 
>                                                     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: trollWalk1.png
>                                                        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
>                                                        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:324)
>                                                        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:298)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:145) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:100) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:92) 
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.Assets.(Assets.java:112) 
>                                                        at com.dotabmot.game.StartMenuScreen.render(StartMenuScreen.java:108) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46) 
>                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531) 
>                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248) 
>   07-24 12:12:14.782 9442-9442/? E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause
>   synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing

Android Studio shows no errors while compiling, how to solve this error?

Here is some code which is related to the error:
Inside Assets Class:

public class Assets {

```
// The Rock Wall Background
public static Texture textureRockWall = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("rockWall.jpg"));
public static TextureRegion rockWall = new TextureRegion(textureRockWall, 0, 0, 600, 450);
// The New Game Button
public static Texture textureNewGameButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("newGameButton.png"));
public static TextureRegion newGameButton = new TextureRegion(textureNewGameButton, 0, 0, 139, 351);
```

Inside the StartMenuScreen Class:

public class StartMenuScreen implements Screen {

public void render(float delta) {

```
    // Draw Background Rock Wall
    batcher.begin();
    batcher.draw(Assets.rockWall, 0, 0, 160, 90); **// THIS LINE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR. IF I REMOVE THIS LINE I GET THE SAME ERROR FOR THE NEXT STATIC OBJECT WHICH IS Assets.newGameButtonClicked...**
    //Screen1
    if(screen1) {
        if(!StartMenuScreenInputHandler.newGameButtonClicked) {
            batcher.draw(Assets.newGameButton, 50, 15, 15, 60);
        } else if(StartMenuScreenInputHandler.newGameButtonClicked){
            batcher.draw(Assets.newGameButtonP, 50, 15, 15, 60);
            if(goAhead){
                goAhead = false;
                StartMenuScreenInputHandler.newGameButtonClicked = false;
                buttonCounter = 0;
                screen1 = false;
                screen2 = true;
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: So hard to tell without seeing any code...

Comment: Hi nasch, I added the related code, since it would be too long to put more. Could you take a look at it again? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is `StartMenuScreen` line 108?

Comment: This is the StartMenuScreen line 108:                                                      "batcher.draw(Assets.rockWall, 0, 0, 160, 90);"

Comment: OK here's the problem, from your stack trace: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: trollWalk1.png`

Comment: Hey Nasch! This annoying piece of asset somehow disappeared from the folder and as you figured, that was the source of the error. I really appreciate your help, thank you so much, the problem is solved!

Comment: @nasch: That would be great if you write your comment as 'answer'. In this way, other people can see this question has been solved and can find the answer quicker. Also you get lots of reputation score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's the problem, from your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: trollWalk1.png
```